# Disable duplicate declaration validation in Acorn

Tags: javascript, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, acorn

I'm using [Acorn](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn) to parse some syntactically valid JavaScript code into an ESTree for further processing.  It appears that Acorn does some semantic checks too - in particular it throws an error for duplicate declarations.  For example, parsing the following code throws an error of `Identifier 'f' has already been declared`:

```
function f() { return 1; }
function f() { return 2; }
```

I do not want such semantic errors to be checked - I'm doing custom processing on the resultant ESTree, so the semantic validity of the source code does not matter to me.

I've looked though the Acorn options for the `parse(input, options)` function, but I could not find anything that sounds like what I want.

Is there a way to disable such semantic checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is no proper way to disable semantic validation.  I managed to get what I want with an ugly hack, by overriding the `raiseRecoverable` method.

This worked for me (note that I'm using TypeScript here, but it would of course be possible to do the same in plain JavaScript):

```
import { Parser } from "acorn";
class SyntacticParser extends Parser {
  raiseRecoverable(pos: any, message: string) {
    if (message.includes("Identifier ") && message.includes(" has already been declared")) return;
    (Parser.prototype as any).raiseRecoverable.call(this, pos, message); // weird call syntax required because the TypeScript types for Parser doesn't contain the `raiseRecoverable` method
  }
}
```

It's an ugly hack because I'm filtering out the duplicate declaration message based on the stringified error message.  However, there does not appear to be a better way.

Comment: According do the official [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn/blob/master/acorn/CHANGELOG.md#new-features-29) introduced as of 3.0.0 (2016-02-10), this seems to be the official way:

> 
> Plugins can now override the raiseRecoverable method to override the way non-critical errors are handled.
>